# Same Calculation on Different Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Apologies if this is a very basic question. I am writing a C# stand alone windows form program to calculate the bending of beams. I have a start page and a button to take me to the beam bending calculation form. It all works fine.

Now I want to extend the program to calculate column loading.

In the first section of the beam bending program the beam sizes are input and the second moment of area of the beam is calculated.

The same input information is required for the column loading program.

How can I 'package up' the input / calculation section so that it can be called from both forms.

Comment: Create a separate class for the calculation that can be called by both forms.

Comment: Your description of the issue isn't quite clear. Are you asking how to pass data between forms? How are you displaying the form? Show? ShowDialog? Do you have an image of your current program/layout?

Comment: Thank you user9938. I want to do a common calculation on both forms

Comment: for a straight just callculate solution you can use a static class to collect all maths. If you need to pass data trough your app you should take a look at classes itself with properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several aproaches, on is a "BeamCalculation"-class looking somethin like this:

```
public static class BeamCalculation
{
    public static float Bending(xxx xxx, ...)
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }
}
```

then you can call your Maths from nearly everywhere with `var result = BeamCalculation.Bending()`

saw your edit, if you want to hold the data you have to change the class to non static and add some properties an pass that object as instance through your forms